# In-Memory SQL-CE

Tags: sql-server-ce, connection-string

Is there a way to connect to a SQL-CE database as a stream?

Specifically, our ASP.Net application builds small SDF at runtime for off-line needs.  When the user is done with his off-line duties, he uploads the SDF and the application imports the new and updated data.  No problems there.

Currently, we're saving the uploaded SDF to the web-server's hard-drive and connecting to the file.  Can we connect to the uploaded SDF without saving it to the hard-drive?  We are using the DbProviderFactory.CreateConnection method, but we're open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must open SQL CE from a file location. Maybe you can use a RAM drive or similar?